# shortest code for css image and class have same name

Tags: css, shortest

Is there some shortest code for css if class and image have same name .. for example I have 10 mages with names like this:

icon-auto.png, icon-tenis.png, icon-calendar.png ... icon-check.png

and class names same name like images

```
<i class="icon-auto"></i>
<i class="icon-tenis"></i>
<i class="icon-calendar"></i>
.
.
.
<i class="icon-check"></i>
```

Is there some code something like this:

```
i [class*="icon-"] {
    background-image: url(img/[class*="icon-"]);
}
```

Comment: Just type it in. Use a good editor (notepad++) and a regex to do the work

Comment: i dont think it is possible with css use JavaScript or jQuery

Comment: `i [class*="icon-"]` will target nothing in your example, just saying, obviously a typo...

Comment: The shortest code would probably be something written in SASS where you can use variables. Other than that you can use javascript and lazy load the images.

Comment: Okay thanks... I think also this is not possible :( only with sass where I can create mixins